# Proving that an injective and surjective linear map is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I'm trying to understand how a surjective and injective linear map is invertible. I'm using Axler's book but I found the proof there hard to follow (in one of the directions only; I can see why an invertible linear map is surjective and injective).

Say $T: V \to W$ is a linear map from vector space $V$ to vector space $W$. It is injective and surjective. I want to prove that there exists a linear map $S:W \to V$ such that $TS = I, ST = I$ where each $I$ is the identity map in $W$ and $V$ respectively.

Axler's proof introduces $S$ as:

> For each $w \in W$, define $Sw$ to be the unique element of $V$ such
> that $TSw$ = $w$ (the existence and uniqueness of such an element
> follow from the surjectivity and injectivity of $T$).

First of all, what is $S$ here? Is it a function or some sort of operator? Or is it a linear map $S:W \to V$?

But the proof ends with a final section:

> To complete the proof, we need to show that $S$ is linear

So $S$ was not a linear map, then what was it?

#### If $S$ can be taken as a linear map

- If I assume $S:W \to V$, I can use the surjective $T$ to say that $\exists v \in V$ such that $Tv = w \forall w \in W$.
- Additionally with injective $T$, $\forall w_1, w_2 \in W$ such that $w_1 \neq w_2$ we know $v_1, v_2 \in V$ exists such that $Tv_1 = w_1, Tv_2 = w_2$. If $v_1 = v_2$ then $Tv_1 = Tv_2 \implies w_1 = w_2$ which contradicts our assumption that $w_1 \neq w_2$. So $v_1 \neq v_2$. So $w_1 \neq w_2 \implies v_1 \neq v_2$.
- Define $S$ as a map from each $w \in W$ to a unique (proved to exist in previous point) $v \in V$ such that $Sw = v$ where $Tv = w$. So $TSw = Tv= w$.

Is this a valid way to interpret Axler's bracketed text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is the following.

Let $T: V \to W$ be a linear map that is both injective and surjective. We want to construct an inverse $S: W \to V$. (

Given $w \in W$, how would we define $Sw \in V?$ Well, since $T$ is injective and surjective, there exists a unique element $v \in V$ with $Tv = w$. This uniqueness allows us to define $Sw:= v$.

Axler used suggestive notation and immediately wrote $v = Sw.$

Note that you only need to check that $S$ is an inverse of $T$ and not that it is linear. The inverse of a linear map is always automatically linear (exercise!).

Comment: But what is $Sw$? I assume it cannot be a linear map since "To complete the proof, we need to show that S is linear" is the last section of the proof.

Comment: I told you what $Sw$ is: it is the unique element $v \in V$ satisfying $Tv = w$. Once you have shown that $S$ is inverse to $T$, linearity comes for free. Indeed, $S( v+w) = S(TSv + TSw) = S(T(Sv+Sw)) = Sv + Sw$ and similarly for scalar multiplication.

Comment: Thanks for the useful note about the inverse. So I guess $S$ at first is simply a map, _not necessarily linear_?

Comment: @sprajagopal Yes, you first define $S$ as a map. A priori, you don't know it is linear. Then, you notice that $S$ is inverse to $T$, and then by my previous comment $S$ will be linear.

Answer (score 1):

Here, $S$ is a map from $W$ to $V$. Asserting that $T\colon V\longrightarrow W$ is invertible means that there is a linear map from $W$ to $V$ such that:

- $(\forall v\in V):S(T(v))=v$;
- $(\forall w\in W):T(S(w))=w$.

Comment: To complete the proof, we need to show that S is linear" is the last section of the proof. So at the beginning there is no assumption that $S$ is a linear map. Is it possible it's a _different kind_ of map?

Comment: Axler first defines a map $S\colon W\longrightarrow V$ and then he proves that $S$ is linear.

Answer (score 0):

If $T:V\to W$ is a linear map then also it is a function.

It is well known that a function is bijective if and only if it has an inverse.

Also it is well known that this inverse is unique.

Denoting this inverse as $S:W\to V$ we have $T\circ S=\mathsf{id}_W$ and $S\circ T=\mathsf{id}_V$.

What remains now is proving that this $S$ is a linear map.